# JDBC Postgres having "This connection has been closed" error

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have problem when my application server lost connection to Postgres. This happens when network outtage, Postgres db restart, etc.

I am able to replicate the problem by restarting my Postgres service (on Windows) then my appserver (Java-spark) got those error.

I know this problem might be related to jdbc property such as testOnBorrow, validationQuery,removeAbandoned. But I just can't make it work.
For reference, here is my connection code :

```
Class.forName(this.config.get("class"));

//create the connection object
connect = DriverManager.getConnection(this.config.get("dsn"), this.config.get("username"), this.config.get("password"));
```

while my DSN is :

```
jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/mydb?testOnBorrow=true&removeAbandoned=true&validationQuery="select 1"
```

I need help to configure jdbc so it able to reconnect when db-connection lost.

Comment: This is why people use connection pools.

Comment: Im also tried using connection pool from this reference (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html), still no luck

Comment: Properties testOnBorrow, validationQuery,removeAbandoned are of a specific connection pool implementation, not of a JDBC driver.